# Group Non-Contiguous Dates By Criteria In Column (Follow Up)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I had this question answered in this post but have been advised to re-ask this as a new question:

[Group Non-Contiguous Dates By Criteria In Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090766/group-non-contiguous-dates-by-criteria-in-column)

However, I have noticed that while the solution works most of the time, there are some errors which trickle through where it doesn't seem to group things together correctly.

For Example,

Data:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE([CUSTOMER_ID] INT
                        ,[TEAM] VARCHAR(1)
                        ,[TYPE] VARCHAR(1)
                        ,[START_DATE] DATETIME
                        ,[END_DATE] DATETIME
                        ,[GROUP_DAYS_CRITERIA] INT)

INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES (1,'A','A','2013-08-07','2013-12-31',28)
                             ,(2,'B','A','2015-05-15','2015-05-28',28)
                             ,(2,'B','A','2015-05-15','2016-05-12',28)
                             ,(2,'B','A','2015-05-28','2015-05-28',28)
                             ,(3,'C','A','2013-05-27','2014-07-23',28)
                             ,(3,'C','A','2015-01-12','2015-05-28',28)
                             ,(3,'B','A','2015-01-12','2015-05-28',28)
                             ,(3,'C','A','2015-05-28','2015-05-28',28)
                             ,(3,'C','A','2015-05-28','2015-12-17',28)
                             ,(4,'A','B','2013-07-09','2014-04-21',7)
                             ,(4,'A','B','2014-04-29','2014-08-01',7)
                             ,(5,'A','A','2014-05-15','2015-04-24',28)
                             ,(5,'A','A','2014-05-15','2015-04-24',28)
                             ,(5,'A','A','2014-05-15','2014-05-15',28)
                             ,(5,'A','A','2015-04-24','2015-05-13',28)
                             ,(5,'A','B','2014-05-15','2014-05-15',7)
                             ,(5,'A','B','2014-06-13','2015-04-24',7)
                             ,(5,'A','B','2014-06-13','2015-04-24',7)
                             ,(5,'A','B','2015-04-24','2015-05-13',7)
                             ,(6,'A','A','2015-02-17','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(6,'A','A','2015-02-17','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(6,'A','A','2015-04-10','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(6,'A','A','2015-04-10','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(6,'A','A','2015-04-28','2015-06-04',28)
                             ,(6,'A','A','2015-04-28','2015-08-03',28)
                             ,(6,'A','A','2015-05-22','2015-08-03',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-03-30','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-03-30','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-03-30','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-03-30','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-04-28','2015-11-17',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-04-28','2015-11-17',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-05-12','2015-11-17',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-05-12','2015-11-17',28)
```

Which looks like this:

```
+-------------+------+------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| CUSTOMER_ID | TEAM | TYPE | START_DATE |  END_DATE  | GROUP_DAYS_CRITERIA |
+-------------+------+------+------------+------------+---------------------+
|           1 | A    | A    | 07/08/2013 | 31/12/2013 |                  28 |
|           2 | B    | A    | 15/05/2015 | 28/05/2015 |                  28 |
|           2 | B    | A    | 15/05/2015 | 12/05/2016 |                  28 |
|           2 | B    | A    | 28/05/2015 | 28/05/2015 |                  28 |
|           3 | C    | A    | 27/05/2013 | 23/07/2014 |                  28 |
|           3 | C    | A    | 12/01/2015 | 28/05/2015 |                  28 |
|           3 | B    | A    | 12/01/2015 | 28/05/2015 |                  28 |
|           3 | C    | A    | 28/05/2015 | 28/05/2015 |                  28 |
|           3 | C    | A    | 28/05/2015 | 17/12/2015 |                  28 |
|           4 | A    | B    | 09/07/2013 | 21/04/2014 |                   7 |
|           4 | A    | B    | 29/04/2014 | 01/08/2014 |                   7 |
|           5 | A    | A    | 15/05/2014 | 24/04/2015 |                  28 |
|           5 | A    | A    | 15/05/2014 | 24/04/2015 |                  28 |
|           5 | A    | A    | 15/05/2014 | 15/05/2014 |                  28 |
|           5 | A    | A    | 24/04/2015 | 13/05/2015 |                  28 |
|           5 | A    | B    | 15/05/2014 | 15/05/2014 |                   7 |
|           5 | A    | B    | 13/06/2014 | 24/04/2015 |                   7 |
|           5 | A    | B    | 13/06/2014 | 24/04/2015 |                   7 |
|           5 | A    | B    | 24/04/2015 | 13/05/2015 |                   7 |
|           6 | A    | A    | 17/02/2015 | 28/04/2015 |                  28 |
|           6 | A    | A    | 17/02/2015 | 28/04/2015 |                  28 |
|           6 | A    | A    | 10/04/2015 | 28/04/2015 |                  28 |
|           6 | A    | A    | 10/04/2015 | 28/04/2015 |                  28 |
|           6 | A    | A    | 28/04/2015 | 04/06/2015 |                  28 |
|           6 | A    | A    | 28/04/2015 | 03/08/2015 |                  28 |
|           6 | A    | A    | 22/05/2015 | 03/08/2015 |                  28 |
|           7 | A    | A    | 30/03/2015 | 28/04/2015 |                  28 |
|           7 | A    | A    | 30/03/2015 | 28/04/2015 |                  28 |
|           7 | A    | A    | 30/03/2015 | 28/04/2015 |                  28 |
|           7 | A    | A    | 30/03/2015 | 28/04/2015 |                  28 |
|           7 | A    | A    | 28/04/2015 | 17/11/2015 |                  28 |
|           7 | A    | A    | 28/04/2015 | 17/11/2015 |                  28 |
|           7 | A    | A    | 12/05/2015 | 17/11/2015 |                  28 |
|           7 | A    | A    | 12/05/2015 | 17/11/2015 |                  28 |
+-------------+------+------+------------+------------+---------------------+
```

It is currently coming out like this:

```
+-------------+------+------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| Customer_Id | Team | Type | Start_Date |  End_Date  | Group_Days_Criteria |
+-------------+------+------+------------+------------+---------------------+
|           1 | A    | A    | 07/08/2013 | 31/12/2013 |                  28 |
|           2 | B    | A    | 15/05/2015 | 12/05/2016 |                  28 |
|           3 | B    | A    | 12/01/2015 | 28/05/2015 |                  28 |
|           3 | C    | A    | 27/05/2013 | 23/07/2014 |                  28 |
|           3 | C    | A    | 12/01/2015 | 28/05/2015 |                  28 |
|           4 | A    | B    | 09/07/2013 | 21/04/2014 |                   7 |
|           4 | A    | B    | 29/04/2014 | 01/08/2014 |                   7 |
|           5 | A    | A    | 15/05/2014 | 24/04/2015 |                  28 |
|           5 | A    | B    | 15/05/2014 | 15/05/2014 |                   7 |
|           5 | A    | B    | 13/06/2014 | 24/04/2015 |                   7 |
|           5 | A    | A    | 24/04/2015 | 13/05/2015 |                  28 |
|           6 | A    | A    | 17/02/2015 | 28/04/2015 |                  28 |
|           7 | A    | A    | 30/03/2015 | 28/04/2015 |                  28 |
+-------------+------+------+------------+------------+---------------------+
```

I need it to come out like this:

```
+-------------+------+------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| CUSTOMER_ID | TEAM | TYPE | START_DATE |  END_DATE  | GROUP_DAYS_CRITERIA |
+-------------+------+------+------------+------------+---------------------+
|           1 | A    | A    | 07/08/2013 | 31/12/2013 |                  28 |
|           2 | B    | A    | 15/05/2015 | 28/05/2015 |                  28 |
|           3 | C    | A    | 27/05/2013 | 23/07/2014 |                  28 |
|           3 | C    | A    | 12/01/2015 | 17/12/2015 |                  28 |
|           3 | B    | A    | 12/01/2015 | 28/05/2015 |                  28 |
|           4 | A    | B    | 09/07/2013 | 21/04/2014 |                   7 |
|           4 | A    | B    | 29/04/2014 | 01/08/2014 |                   7 |
|           5 | A    | A    | 15/05/2014 | 13/05/2015 |                  28 |
|           5 | A    | B    | 15/05/2014 | 15/05/2014 |                   7 |
|           5 | A    | B    | 13/06/2014 | 13/05/2015 |                   7 |
|           6 | A    | A    | 17/02/2015 | 03/08/2015 |                  28 |
|           7 | A    | A    | 30/03/2015 | 17/11/2015 |                  28 |
+-------------+------+------+------------+------------+---------------------+
```

Any ideas on how I could fix this whilst still maintaining the criteria for the correct output?

Daniel

Comment: What is the logic for resolving the duplicate team/type pairs?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen in the results first and last row are contiguous in dates term.First row ends at the `24/04/2015` and picks up in the 4th row continuing up to 13/05/2015

Comment: You should ask the person who gave you the first answer for help.

Comment: The logic is described as best as I can in the referenced post that was answered by @RexMaison - I am they may look at this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have cracked it using a set (messy though)...

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE([CUSTOMER_ID] INT
                        ,[TEAM] VARCHAR(1)
                        ,[TYPE] VARCHAR(1)
                        ,[START_DATE] DATETIME
                        ,[END_DATE] DATETIME
                        ,[GROUP_DAYS_CRITERIA] INT)

INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES (1,'A','A','2013-08-07','2013-12-31',28)
                             ,(2,'B','A','2015-05-15','2015-05-28',28)
                             ,(2,'B','A','2015-05-15','2016-05-12',28)
                             ,(2,'B','A','2015-05-28','2015-05-28',28)
                             ,(3,'C','A','2013-05-27','2014-07-23',28)
                             ,(3,'C','A','2015-01-12','2015-05-28',28)
                             ,(3,'B','A','2015-01-12','2015-05-28',28)
                             ,(3,'C','A','2015-05-28','2015-05-28',28)
                             ,(3,'C','A','2015-05-28','2015-12-17',28)
                             ,(4,'A','B','2013-07-09','2014-04-21',7)
                             ,(4,'A','B','2014-04-29','2014-08-01',7)
                             ,(5,'A','A','2014-05-15','2015-04-24',28)
                             ,(5,'A','A','2014-05-15','2015-04-24',28)
                             ,(5,'A','A','2014-05-15','2014-05-15',28)
                             ,(5,'A','A','2015-04-24','2015-05-13',28)
                             ,(5,'A','B','2014-05-15','2014-05-15',7)
                             ,(5,'A','B','2014-06-13','2015-04-24',7)
                             ,(5,'A','B','2014-06-13','2015-04-24',7)
                             ,(5,'A','B','2015-04-24','2015-05-13',7)
                             ,(6,'A','A','2015-02-17','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(6,'A','A','2015-02-17','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(6,'A','A','2015-04-10','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(6,'A','A','2015-04-10','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(6,'A','A','2015-04-28','2015-06-04',28)
                             ,(6,'A','A','2015-04-28','2015-08-03',28)
                             ,(6,'A','A','2015-05-22','2015-08-03',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-03-30','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-03-30','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-03-30','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-03-30','2015-04-28',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-04-28','2015-11-17',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-04-28','2015-11-17',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-05-12','2015-11-17',28)
                             ,(7,'A','A','2015-05-12','2015-11-17',28)

DECLARE @Holding TABLE([CUSTOMER_ID] INT
                      ,[TEAM] VARCHAR(1)
                      ,[TYPE] VARCHAR(1)
                      ,[START_DATE] DATETIME
                      ,[END_DATE] DATETIME
                      ,[GROUP_DAYS_CRITERIA] INT
                      ,[START_ROW_ORDER] INT
                      ,[END_ROW_ORDER] INT)

INSERT INTO @Holding

SELECT TT.[CUSTOMER_ID]
      ,TT.[TEAM]
      ,TT.[TYPE]
      ,TT.[START_DATE]
      ,TT.[END_DATE]
      ,TT.[GROUP_DAYS_CRITERIA]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TT.[CUSTOMER_ID],TT.[TEAM],TT.[TYPE] ORDER BY TT.[START_DATE]) [START_ROW_ORDER]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TT.[CUSTOMER_ID],TT.[TEAM],TT.[TYPE] ORDER BY CASE WHEN TT.[END_DATE] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,TT.[END_DATE]) [END_ROW_ORDER]

FROM @TempTable TT

SELECT DISTINCT C.[CUSTOMER_ID]
               ,C.[TEAM]
               ,C.[TYPE]
              ,CASE WHEN C.[GROUP_ON_PREVIOUS] = 1 THEN LAG(C.[START_DATE]) OVER (PARTITION BY C.[CUSTOMER_ID],C.[TEAM],C.[TYPE] ORDER BY C.[START_DATE])
                    ELSE C.[START_DATE]
               END [START_DATE]
              ,CASE WHEN C.[GROUP_ON_NEXT] = 1 THEN LEAD(C.[END_DATE]) OVER (PARTITION BY C.[CUSTOMER_ID],C.[TEAM],C.[TYPE] ORDER BY C.[START_DATE])
                    ELSE C.[END_DATE]
               END [END_DATE]

FROM(SELECT A.[CUSTOMER_ID]
           ,A.[TEAM]
           ,A.[TYPE]
           ,A.[START_DATE]
           ,B.[END_DATE]
           ,CASE WHEN A.[START_DATE] <= DATEADD(DAY,A.[GROUP_DAYS_CRITERIA],LAG(B.[END_DATE]) OVER (PARTITION BY A.[CUSTOMER_ID],A.[TEAM],A.[TYPE] ORDER BY A.[START_ROW_ORDER])) THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END [GROUP_ON_PREVIOUS]
           ,CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY,A.[GROUP_DAYS_CRITERIA],B.[END_DATE]) >= LEAD(A.[START_DATE]) OVER (PARTITION BY A.[CUSTOMER_ID],A.[TEAM],A.[TYPE] ORDER BY A.[START_ROW_ORDER]) THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END [GROUP_ON_NEXT]

    FROM @Holding A

    INNER JOIN @Holding B ON A.[CUSTOMER_ID] = B.[CUSTOMER_ID]
                         AND A.[TEAM] = B.[TEAM]
                         AND A.[TYPE] = B.[TYPE]
                         AND A.[START_ROW_ORDER] = B.[END_ROW_ORDER]) C

WHERE NOT (C.[GROUP_ON_PREVIOUS] = 1 AND C.[GROUP_ON_NEXT] = 1)
```

Returns rows in less than a second

Answer (score 2):

```
Select A.Customer_ID
      ,A.Team
      ,A.Type
      ,Group_Days_Criteria
      ,Start_Date = B.MinD
      ,End_Date   = max(B.MaxD)
 From  @TempTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select MinD=min(Start_Date),MaxD=Max(End_Date)
                  From @TempTable 
                  Where (Start_Date between A.Start_Date and A.End_Date or
                         End_Date   between A.Start_Date and A.End_Date)
                    and Customer_ID = A.Customer_ID
                    and Team = A.Team
                    and Type = A.TYPE
                    and Group_Days_Criteria = A.Group_Days_Criteria
             ) B
 Group By 
       A.Customer_ID
      ,A.Team
      ,A.Type
      ,A.Group_Days_Criteria
      ,B.MinD
```

Returns

```
Customer_ID Team    Type    Group_Days_Criteria Start_Date  End_Date
1           A       A       28                  2014-05-15  2015-05-13 
1           A       B       7                   2014-05-15  2014-05-15 
1           A       B       7                   2014-06-13  2015-05-13
```

Comment: Works for the provided example data. very nice!

Comment: @DanielHitchcock Sample to Production is alway my concern.  I saw a pattern and ran with it.  I'll noodle it a bit more.

Comment: Thanks @John! I am happy to provide more examples - Just didn't want to clutter the original query.

Comment: Hi @JohnCappelletti I have updated the original question with the additional data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more complicated question than I assumed when I first started playing with it.  I had to come up with a totally different way of doing things than my previous answer.  That answer would look back a row or two to compare dates.  That is not sufficient since we have such irregular ranges for our consultations.  In the end, the previous answer had a query that was very fragile in the real world, as we saw.

We need to loop through each consultation for each grouping of Customer, Team and Type - and compare our consult dates that way.  This solution compares each consultation to the first consultation by grouping.  It updates the end date of the first consultation if the row at hand falls within the date range of that consultation.  If the row at hand falls outside of that date range, a row is inserted.  Continuing on in our loops,  we will no longer consider the first consultation.  Future comparisons will be made to the row we inserted until consultations no longer fall within that second date range.

This completes in under a second on my machine.

I added a new answer so you can see where my first train of thought was not going to work from the start.  Please let me know if you have any questions.

**Setup and Return Results:**

```
declare @TempTable table
(
    [CUSTOMER_ID] INT
    ,[TEAM] VARCHAR(1)
    ,[TYPE] VARCHAR(1)
    ,[START_DATE] DATETIME
    ,[END_DATE] DATETIME
    ,[GROUP_DAYS_CRITERIA] INT
)

INSERT INTO @tempTable 
VALUES 
    (1,'A','A','2013-08-07','2013-12-31',28)
    ,(2,'B','A','2015-05-15','2015-05-28',28)
    ,(2,'B','A','2015-05-15','2016-05-12',28)
    ,(2,'B','A','2015-05-28','2015-05-28',28)
    ,(3,'C','A','2013-05-27','2014-07-23',28)
    ,(3,'C','A','2015-01-12','2015-05-28',28)
    ,(3,'B','A','2015-01-12','2015-05-28',28)
    ,(3,'C','A','2015-05-28','2015-05-28',28)
    ,(3,'C','A','2015-05-28','2015-12-17',28)
    ,(4,'A','B','2013-07-09','2014-04-21',7)
    ,(4,'A','B','2014-04-29','2014-08-01',7)
    ,(5,'A','A','2014-05-15','2015-04-24',28)
    ,(5,'A','A','2014-05-15','2015-04-24',28)
    ,(5,'A','A','2014-05-15','2014-05-15',28)
    ,(5,'A','A','2015-04-24','2015-05-13',28)
    ,(5,'A','B','2014-05-15','2014-05-15',7)
    ,(5,'A','B','2014-06-13','2015-04-24',7)
    ,(5,'A','B','2014-06-13','2015-04-24',7)
    ,(5,'A','B','2015-04-24','2015-05-13',7)
    ,(6,'A','A','2015-02-17','2015-04-28',28)
    ,(6,'A','A','2015-02-17','2015-04-28',28)
    ,(6,'A','A','2015-04-10','2015-04-28',28)
    ,(6,'A','A','2015-04-10','2015-04-28',28)
    ,(6,'A','A','2015-04-28','2015-06-04',28)
    ,(6,'A','A','2015-04-28','2015-08-03',28)
    ,(6,'A','A','2015-05-22','2015-08-03',28)
    ,(7,'A','A','2015-03-30','2015-04-28',28)
    ,(7,'A','A','2015-03-30','2015-04-28',28)
    ,(7,'A','A','2015-03-30','2015-04-28',28)
    ,(7,'A','A','2015-03-30','2015-04-28',28)
    ,(7,'A','A','2015-04-28','2015-11-17',28)
    ,(7,'A','A','2015-04-28','2015-11-17',28)
    ,(7,'A','A','2015-05-12','2015-11-17',28)
    ,(7,'A','A','2015-05-12','2015-11-17',28)

-- renamed work table columns for ease of typing
-- note: try to avoid using reserved words (type) for column names
declare @prepTable table -- temp table with row number for loops, padded end date for comparison
(
    [CustomerId] INT
    ,[Team] VARCHAR(1)
    ,[ConsultType] VARCHAR(1)
    ,[StartDate] DATETIME
    ,[EndDate] DATETIME
    ,[GroupDaysCriteria] INT
    ,ConsultEndDate datetime
    ,rn int
);

declare @ConsolidateConsults table -- consult work table 
(
    [CustomerId] INT
    ,[Team] VARCHAR(1)
    ,[ConsultType] VARCHAR(1)
    ,[StartDate] DATETIME
    ,[EndDate] DATETIME
    ,[GroupDaysCriteria] INT
    ,ConsultEndDate datetime
    ,ConsultGroup int
);

declare @CustomerTeamType table -- temp lookup table for loops
(
    [CustomerId] INT
    ,CustomerNumber int
    ,[Team] VARCHAR(1)
    ,TeamId int
    ,[ConsultType] VARCHAR(1)
    ,ConsultTypeId int
    ,ConsultCount int
);

insert into @CustomerTeamType
select  Customer_Id,
        null,
        Team,
        null as TeamId,
        [Type],
        null as ConsultTypeId,
        count(*)
from @TempTable
group by Customer_Id, Team, [Type];


update c 
set CustomerNumber = ctt.CustomerNumber,
    TeamId = ctt.TeamId,
    ConsultTypeId = ctt.ConsultTypeId
from @CustomerTeamType c
    inner join 
    (
        select  ct.CustomerId,
                ct.Team,
                ct.ConsultType,
                dense_rank() over (partition by 1 order by ct.CustomerId) as CustomerNumber,
                dense_rank() over (partition by ct.CustomerId order by ct.Team) as TeamId,
                dense_rank() over (partition by ct.CustomerId, ct.Team order by ct.ConsultType) as ConsultTypeId
        from @CustomerTeamType ct
    ) as ctt 
on c.CustomerId = ctt.CustomerId
    and c.Team = ctt.Team
    and c.ConsultType = ctt.ConsultType;


insert into @prepTable
select  Customer_Id,
        Team,
        [Type],
        [Start_Date],
        [End_Date],
        Group_Days_Criteria,
        dateadd(day, Group_Days_Criteria, [End_Date]),
        row_number() over (partition by Customer_Id, Team, [Type] order by [Start_Date] asc, [End_Date] desc) 
from @tempTable;


insert into @ConsolidateConsults
select  CustomerId,
        Team,
        ConsultType,
        StartDate,
        EndDate,
        GroupDaysCriteria,
        ConsultEndDate,
        1 -- rn of one indicates a sure consult begin date
from @prepTable
where rn = 1;

--prepare loop counters and end points
declare @consultGroup int = 1;
declare @customer int = 1;
declare @team int = 1;
declare @consultType int = 1;

declare @maxCustomer int = (select max(CustomerNumber) from @CustomerTeamType);

declare @maxTeam int;
declare @maxConsultType int;
declare @totalConsults int;

-- loop through each consult in each consult type in each consult team for each customer 

while @customer <= @maxCustomer
    begin

        -- Get total conult teams for customer x 
        set @maxTeam = (select max(TeamId) 
                        from @CustomerTeamType 
                        where CustomerNumber = @customer
        );

        while @team <= @maxTeam
            begin

                -- get total consult types for customer x, team y
                set @maxConsultType = (select max(ConsultTypeId) from @CustomerTeamType where CustomerNumber = @customer and TeamId = @team)

                while @consultType <= @maxConsultType
                    begin

                        -- get total consults for customer x, team y, consult type z
                        set @totalConsults = (select ConsultCount from @CustomerTeamType where CustomerNumber = @customer and TeamId = @team and @consultType = ConsultTypeId)

                        -- reset to first consult 
                        declare @consult int = 1

                    while @consult <= @totalConsults
                        begin
                            declare @row table ( -- table to hold one consult at a time
                                CustomerId int,
                                Team varchar(1), 
                                ConsultType varchar(1),
                                StartDate datetime,
                                EndDate datetime,
                                GroupDaysCriteria int,
                                ConsultEndDate datetime,
                                ConsultGroup int
                            )

                            insert into @row
                            select  pt.CustomerId,
                                    pt.Team,
                                    pt.ConsultType,
                                    pt.StartDate,
                                    pt.EndDate,
                                    pt.GroupDaysCriteria,
                                    pt.ConsultEndDate,
                                    @consultGroup
                            from @prepTable pt
                                inner join @CustomerTeamType ctt
                                    on pt.CustomerId = ctt.CustomerId
                                        and pt.Team = ctt.Team
                                        and pt.ConsultType = ctt.ConsultType
                                        and ctt.CustomerNumber = @customer 
                                        and ctt.ConsultTypeId = @consultType
                                        and ctt.TeamId = @team
                                        and pt.rn = @consult            

                            -- if row at hand falls within previous consult, update end date to greater of end dates 
                            if exists (
                                select * from @row r 
                                inner join @ConsolidateConsults cc 
                                    on r.CustomerId = cc.CustomerId                                 
                                        and r.ConsultType = cc.ConsultType
                                        and r.Team = cc.Team
                                        and cc.ConsultGroup = @consultGroup
                                        and r.StartDate >= cc.StartDate 
                                        and r.StartDate <= cc.ConsultEndDate
                            )
                                Begin
                                    update cc                       
                                    set cc.ConsultEndDate = case when cc.ConsultEndDate > r.ConsultEndDate then cc.ConsultEndDate else r.ConsultEndDate end,
                                        cc.EndDate = case when cc.EndDate > r.EndDate then cc.EndDate else r.EndDate end
                                    from @ConsolidateConsults cc
                                    inner join @row r 
                                        on r.CustomerId = cc.CustomerId 
                                            and r.Team = cc.Team
                                            and @consultGroup = cc.ConsultGroup 
                                            and r.ConsultType = cc.ConsultType
                                            and cc.ConsultGroup = @consultGroup

                                    --set @updates = @updates + 1
                                end
                            -- if row at hand falls after existing consultation, create a new row and grouping    
                            else 
                                begin
                                    -- increment consult grouping so next loop considers proper consultation
                                    set @consultGroup = @consultGroup + 1

                                    insert into @ConsolidateConsults
                                    select  CustomerId,
                                            Team,
                                            ConsultType,
                                            StartDate,
                                            EndDate,
                                            GroupDaysCriteria,
                                            ConsultEndDate,
                                            @consultGroup
                                    from @row                       

                                end
                            set @consult = @consult + 1 -- move to next record
                            delete @row -- delete record we have just compared          
                        end -- finished individual consultations for customer x, team y, consult type z

                    set @consultType = @consultType + 1 --move to next consult type
                    set @consultGroup = 1 -- reset conultation grouping 
                end -- finished comparing for consult type 

                set @consultType = 1 -- reset consult type
                set @consultGroup = 1 -- reset conultation grouping     
                set @team = @team + 1 -- move to next team          
            end  -- finished consult teams 

        set @team = 1 -- reset consult team 
        set @consultGroup = 1  -- reset conultation grouping 
        set @customer = @customer + 1 -- move to next customer 
    end -- finished customer

--  get output
select  CustomerId as Customer_Id,
        Team,
        ConsultType as [Type],
        StartDate as [Start_Date],
        EndDate as [End_Date],

from @ConsolidateConsults   
order by CustomerId, Team, ConsultType, StartDate
```

**Query Returns:**

```
╔═════════════╦══════╦══════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ Customer_Id ║ Team ║ Type ║       Start_Date        ║        End_Date         ║ Group_Days_Criteria ║
╠═════════════╬══════╬══════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║           1 ║ A    ║ A    ║ 2013-08-07 00:00:00.000 ║ 2013-12-31 00:00:00.000 ║                  28 ║
║           2 ║ B    ║ A    ║ 2015-05-15 00:00:00.000 ║ 2016-05-12 00:00:00.000 ║                  28 ║
║           3 ║ B    ║ A    ║ 2015-01-12 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-05-28 00:00:00.000 ║                  28 ║
║           3 ║ C    ║ A    ║ 2013-05-27 00:00:00.000 ║ 2014-07-23 00:00:00.000 ║                  28 ║
║           3 ║ C    ║ A    ║ 2015-01-12 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-12-17 00:00:00.000 ║                  28 ║
║           4 ║ A    ║ B    ║ 2013-07-09 00:00:00.000 ║ 2014-04-21 00:00:00.000 ║                   7 ║
║           4 ║ A    ║ B    ║ 2014-04-29 00:00:00.000 ║ 2014-08-01 00:00:00.000 ║                   7 ║
║           5 ║ A    ║ A    ║ 2014-05-15 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 ║                  28 ║
║           5 ║ A    ║ B    ║ 2014-05-15 00:00:00.000 ║ 2014-05-15 00:00:00.000 ║                   7 ║
║           5 ║ A    ║ B    ║ 2014-06-13 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-05-13 00:00:00.000 ║                   7 ║
║           6 ║ A    ║ A    ║ 2015-02-17 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-08-03 00:00:00.000 ║                  28 ║
║           7 ║ A    ║ A    ║ 2015-03-30 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-11-17 00:00:00.000 ║                  28 ║
╚═════════════╩══════╩══════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response! Thank you @RexMaison for this answer! It works although, I will say, that in a production environment, it quite resource heavy - Taking 45 minutes to return 14,000 rows.

Comment: I am glad it works for you, @DanielHitchcock.  It is definitely a beast and not set based.  I think this approach could be improved by using temp tables with indexes instead of using table variables.

The best course of action would be to redesign this table, or ETL the data into a reporting table based on a trigger or schedule where you could better assign a grouping indicator and/or time span to each consultation group.